# Hadoop job stuck due to connection timeout

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop.I have set up hadoop in my mac system, then I am trying to run following:

```
 hadoop jar wordcount.jar /usr/joy/input /usr/joy/output
```

In response to the command, following message got printed in terminal,

```
 16/03/18 17:13:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load 
 native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes 
 where applicable 16/03/18 17:13:20 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to   
 ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
 16/03/18 17:13:21 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-
 line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and
 execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
 16/03/18 17:13:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to
 process : 1
 16/03/18 17:13:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
 16/03/18 17:13:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for 
 job: job_1458279089418_0002
 16/03/18 17:13:21 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application   
 application_1458279089418_0002
 16/03/18 17:13:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job:

 http://EN-AbhishekM:8088/proxy/application_1458279089418_0002/
```

Now while I am checking status of the job at browser, in logs I found following error:

```
 Application application_1458279089418_0001 failed 2 times due to Error
 launching appattempt_1458279089418_0001_000002. Got exception: 
 org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From
 EN-AbhishekM/192.168.0.102 to 192.168.43.66:61029 
 failed on socket timeout exception:
  org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout
   while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : 
  java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending 
  remote=192.168.43.66/192.168.43.66:61029];....
```

I am pasting configuration files here:

core-site.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
 <configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  </configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
   <configuration>
   <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
   </configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
  <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  </configuration>
```

Formatted the filesystem by:

```
 bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

started namenode and datanode daemon by:

```
  sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Started ResourceManager daemon and NodeManager daemon by:

```
  sbin/start-yarn.sh
```

Can please anyone suggest me what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Are you running hadoop on different machine? I think you should check the master slave file

Comment: No, on the same machine only.

Comment: can you run command jps to make sure all required hadoop services are actually running?

Comment: I have run jps, it is giving following output:  867 ResourceManager
533 NameNode
613 DataNode
8343 Jps
8344 FsShell
952 NodeManager
716 SecondaryNameNode
335